# how to calculate errors in a derived quantity in Python

Tags: python, math, uncertainty

I have two quantities `x` and `y` and their covariance matrix `cov(x,y)`, and I want to calculate the error in a derived quantity `z=1/(x-y)`. Is there is a package to calculate mean value of `z` and `sigma(xz)` and `sigma(zy)`  ?

thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1):

The derived quantity will generally not follow a normal distribution, given that `y` and `x` does. You can estimate the error distribution numerically:

```
import scipy.stats
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# sample from multivariate normal
x = scipy.stats.multivariate_normal(mean=[0,1], cov=[[1,0.5],[0.5,2]]).rvs(10000)
z = 1 / (x[0] - x[1])
print(z.mean())
print(z.var())
# Create kde of the distribution
kde = scipy.stats.gaussian_kde(z)
grid = np.linspace(z.min(), z.max(), 1000)
plt.plot(grid, kde.evaluate(grid))
plt.show()
```